# Display more digits of p-value digits from adfTest when p-value<0.01

Tags: r

When I run the below code several times, the p-value will display more than two digits only when above 0.01. When below 0.01, I cannot access the digits.

How can I get more digits ?

```
library(fUnitRoots)
x = rnorm(13)
y = rnorm(13)
m <- lm(y ~ x + 0)
adfTest(coredata(resid(m)), type="nc")@test$p.value
```

Running several times the above prints:

```
0.01290496626
0.01 (with warning: "p-value smaller than printed p-value")
0.01 (with warning: "p-value smaller than printed p-value")
0.08404833863
```

Comment: `unclass` your P-value.

Comment: @HongOoi Doesn't work. Looks like the warning comes from the `adfTest` call, and this value in the warning is stored as a `numeric` (with no further warnings)

Comment: @Metrics, He may need to correct for multiple testing first. Papers doing GWAS (genome wide association studies) routinely report p-values of less than 5e-08.

Comment: For GWAS, you're scanning the genome for markers which are significantly associated with a disease. So maybe you have 1 million markers, and you're fitting a linear model for each one. With a p-value of 0.01, you will still get 1% false positives, so 10,000. Multiple testing correction deals with this by adjusting the p-value so you still only get your desired false positive rate. For example Bonferroni corrected p-value becomes `alpha/n` -> 0.05/1000000 = 5e-08.

This is a common strategy in life sciences due to the large volumes of data and tests being run.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about the command you're running, but I looked through the `adfTest` function and it looks like the do approximation of the p-value based on the `approx` function and a table of critical values, which means that they can't report P-Values < 0.01.